# Always null returned (NPE) on getChildCount - checked everything

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-relativelayout, android-checkbox

OK, so I have multiple RelativeLayouts in different XML files in the *layout* directory. Each is ID'd properly, declared properly, and initialized properly in Java MainActivity.class. These XML files are used by the include tag. I want to un-check all of the CheckBoxes in each RelativeLayout in each XML file. I use the following code (this is for one of the RL's):

```
RelativeLayout rWen; //above onCreate

rWen = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relWends); //in onCreate

    for (int w = 0; w < rWen.getChildCount(); w++) {  //in public void called from button)
        View v = rWen.getChildAt(w);
        if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
            CheckBox wB = (CheckBox)v;
            wB.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

My problem is no matter what I check, Android Studio tells me that rWen has NO children. It's a NPE that says getChildCount returns NULL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relWends"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        ...params/>

    <CheckBox
        ...params/>

    <CheckBox
        ...params/>

    <CheckBox
        ...params/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have gone to the Activity with the relWends first, and it didin't help. I tried switching RL to LL & to ViewGroup, but no joy. Any thoughts, everyone?

Comment: Are you sure that `rWen.getChildCount()` is returning `null`, rather than `rWen` itself being `null`? That seems more likely.

Comment: That error means that `rWen` itself is `null`. It's likely that `findViewById` isn't actually returning anything--make sure that the values are correct.

Comment: But, it's right there in the code: @+id/relWends & R.id.relWends. No red flags at all. Is it because of the includes?

Comment: Post your full activity code if possible

Comment: For which part? I have 8 XML files and 3 Java Classes.

Comment: I tried posting the whole main XML page, and it was over by 3487 characters.

    <ViewFlipper
        ...params>
        <TextView
            ...params/>
        <include        android:id="@+id/wendys_view"           layout="@layout/food_wendys"/>
    </ViewFlipper>

Comment: @Kenyx The most useful part would be the java file that those code snippets are from. At least post the complete `onCreate` method, the root xml view it inflates, and whatever calls the function to check the check boxes.